# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int?>

Tags: c#, linq

I am recieving the following error
Instance argument:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Well the problem is the variable Assay.assayKey could be null in the table so I cannot have int assayKey instead of int? assayKey. I am stumped at this, could some one help??  thanks

```
      Search Entry
        {

        int id {get;set;}
        int? key {get;set;}
        int[] selectedKeys {get;set;}
        }

        Assay
       {
        int id {get;set;}
        int? AssayKey { get; set; }
       }

        CollObject
        {
         Ienumerable<int> keys {get;set;}
        }
```

In my controller action method, am doing the following to retrieve an array of ids:

```
       SearchEntry.selectedKeys = (from assays in db.assay
                                   where CollObject.Keys.Contains(assay.AssayKey)
                                   select assays.id).toArray();
```

Well I found the solution.  Since Assay Key is a nullable int, I just had to do something like this

```
.Contains(assays.AssayKey ??0)
```

Comment: Please never retype your code. It's more beneficial to everyone if you copy/pasted it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was I could not use the .contains on a nullable int, so I had to do something like this to make it work

```
.Contains(assays.AssayKey ??0)
```